# Identifying certain records from a dataset

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, window-functions

This is a follow-up to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857363/identify-sub-set-of-records-based-on-date-and-rules-in-sql-server/37857608?noredirect=1#comment63174472_37857608), now that the requirements have changed again after the analysts clarified the requirements

I have a dataset like the below using the help I received:
[image]

I need to be able to identify row 2, where the `TotalWeeks` column has reached or exceeded 23 weeks, so I can return the correct `ToDate` value.

to get that dataset I am using a query like this:

```
Select 
    idcol
    , FromDate
    , ToDate
    , NoOfDays
    , Weeks
    , Linked 
    , sum(Weeks) over(order by idcol desc) TotalWeeks
    from 
        #tmpAbsences 
    where 
        idcol between 1 AND (
        Select TOP 1 idcol from #tmpAbsences where Linked=0)
    ORDER BY 
        ToDate DESC
```

But how could I alwauys identify the record where the *TotalWeeks* reaches the value I am checking for - either 23 weeks (and less than 28) or greater than or equal to 28 weeks?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried `HAVING()`?  I'm not sure if it works with an `OVER` clause but generically this is what you'd want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the `Having` clause

Something like

```
Having (sum(weeks) >= 23 and SUM(weeks) < 28) or sum(weeks) >= 28
```